# rails enable debug error messages in views when something goes wrong in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've install spree gem and tried to add i18n gem and get the following error:
[image]

I'd like to know what is wrong:
My development.rb file :

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true

  # Asset digests allow you to set far-future HTTP expiration dates on all assets,
  # yet still be able to expire them through the digest params.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Adds additional error checking when serving assets at runtime.
  # Checks for improperly declared sprockets dependencies.
  # Raises helpful error messages.
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true

   Raises error for missing translations
   config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
end
```

How do I enable debug info?

Comment: how did you start the rails app?

Answer (score 0):

`config.consider_all_requests_local       = true` should make you see the error messages.

It looks like you are missing a `#` before `Raises error for missing translations` in your configuration.

Are you rescuing the errors somewhere ? Perhaps you have a `rescue_from` in your application controller? Did you remember to restart your server after changeing the configuration?

Also, I can really recommend the [better_errors](https://github.com/charliesome/better_errors) gem.